# Capitalizing first letter of every word, doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

First of all I know that it is not the right way of doing it, but I want to understand why it is happening so I'll better understand the language.

```
function titleCase(str) {
  let str1 = str.toLowerCase();
  str1 = str1.replace(str1[0], str1[0].toUpperCase());
  console.log(str1);

  for(let i=1; i < str1.length; i++){
    if(str1[i]===' '){
      str1 = str1.replace(str1[i+1], str1[i+1].toUpperCase());
      console.log(i);
      console.log(str1);
    }
  }
  return str1;
}

titleCase("ab cd ef gh ba");
```

So, if the first letter of the last word doesn't appear as second to last letter in any word before it is working, "ab cd ef gh" no problem here, but "ab cd ef gh ba" results in the following output: "AB Cd Ef Gh ba" etc..
Thanks!

Comment: The logic of your function is not correct. You need to reconsider it.

Comment: For the record, this function would be much better as: `titleCase = str => str.replace(/\b[a-z]/, x=>x.toUpperCase());`

Comment: I'd say `replace` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't take an index, it takes a string value (or single character), and replace its *first occurrence*.

Comment: I assume this is what you were alluding to when you mentioned that you know this is not the right way of doing it, but just on the off-chance that it wasn't: python has an easy way to do this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `.replace()` function will replace the *first* occurrence.

```
"Tell us more about your question us"
```

The first time it finds a space, it will replace the first occurrence of a lowercase "u" which happens to be the correct one:

```
"Tell us more about your question us"
//    ^ this "u" happens to be the first occurrence
```

But when it comes to the last word "us", it will again try to find the first occurrence of the lowercase "u", which is the one in the middle of the word "about":

```
"Tell Us More About Your Question us"
//               ^ this "u" is now the first lowercase "u"
```

Answer (score 1):

for sring replacements of that kind id rather use regex

using /\b(.)/g as pattern for the first letter and \U$0 as the substitution string it should work as intended

here is a fiddle for that

https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/423

Answer (score 0):

This is replacing the first occurrence of the character within the string. So characters at earlier positions are potentially replaced as well.

```
str1 = str1.replace(str1[i+1], str1[i+1].toUpperCase());
```